# Define a set outside of a bean in spring ioc

Tags: java, spring, set

I understand that a set can be defined as:

```
<bean id="toolbox" class="tools.Toolbox">
    <property name="tools">
        <set>
            <ref local="foo" />
            <ref local="bar" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

but I can't find anything in the documentation to allow me to define the set first, for example:

```
<set id="myTools">
    <ref local="foo" />
    <ref local="bar" />
</set>
<bean id="toolbox" class="tools.Toolbox">
    <property name="tools" ref="myTools"/>
</bean>
```

Does anyone know if this works or if not how it could be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [util namespace](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-set)

```
<util:set id="myTools">
    <ref local="foo" />
    <ref local="bar" />
</util:set>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `<util:set>`

Here's the namespace:

```
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
```

And the schemaLocation:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
```